# jQuery - How to scroll through children addclass then removeclass in one iteration setTimout not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, settimeout

HTML

```
<div id="slides">  
    <div id="one">Slide 1</div>  
    <div id="two">Slide 2</div>  
    <div id="three">Slide 3</div>  
</div>
```

CSS

```
#slides .show{
    display: block;
}
#slides div{
    display: none;
}
```

Script

```
var slides = $('#slides').children();

var i = 0;
function play(){
    $(slides[i]).addClass('show');
    setTimeout($(slides[i]).removeClass('show'), 500); /* does nothing */
    i++;
    setTimeout(play, 3000); 
}

play();
```

I got this and it displays the slide one by one but it doesn't remove them. Wondering how to set the removeClass to wait for a second before actually removing it.

UPDATED jsfiddle link below

http://jsfiddle.net/WbsxQ/6/

Thanks!

Comment: Could you set up a jsfiddle? Might be easier to help you that way.

Comment: I'm guessing `#carousel` should read `#slides`, no?

Comment: yes #carousel should read slides oops I rewrote the code when I posted on here

Comment: I've updated with a js fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/WbsxQ/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setTimeout fires your loop has been finished long time ago. Try putting the element `slides[i]` - into global variable (you don't need another $ there).

```
elementToHide = slides[i];
setTimeout(function(){elementToHide.removeClass('show')}, 500);
```

Comment: Thanks Litek!! that worked I had to wrap it around a jQuery selector though but it worked! `setTimeout(function(){$(theSlide).removeClass('show')}, 500);`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the only error, but at least, `setTimeout` needs a function (or a string, but let's not go there), not an result of invocation (unless the result is a function or a string... you get the drift)... so,

```
setTimeout(function() { $(slide[i]).removeClass('show') }, 500);
```

(actually it would be prettier if refactored out into a variable, but works for illustrating contrtast)

Comment: I've tried `setTimeout(function() { $(slide[i]).removeClass('show') }, 500);` and console.log(i) returns it as undefined.

Comment: @jshotz:  Why do you have a problem with the result being undefined?